# How to know when bottom nav-bar is visible in mobile safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webkit

So i have this problem where clicking a fixed button on the bottom of the page slides the page up revealing the bottom navigation bar in mobile safari, requiring the button to be clicked a second time in order to work. Adding a `margin-bottom: 50px;` to the button fixes this but when the page is scrolled the margin is a bit much because the nav-bar slides down.

using `safe-area-inset` as margin does not fix the problem. Using it as padding fixes it but it also stretches the element all the way to the bottom of the screen

i also tried the following code, this is supposed to keep the nav bar from hiding. This works but it messes with the window scroll calculations and fixed position elements so it does not solve my problem.

```
html,body{

height: 100%;

overflow-y: scroll;

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Would there be any way to know when the bottom nav bar is visible/hidden using javascript or jquery in mobile safari or any workaround to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a LOT of trial and error i finally came up with a solution to the problem. I was working on a similar website with a header on the bottom of the page instead of a button but the concept is similar.

The header animates in and out on page scroll and fades in after 2.5 seconds of inactivity, 
when the nav bar fades in or out the window `resize` is triggered. If  mobile safari is being used then every time the header fades in and it does not have the right `margin-bottom`, the margin is added. When the nav bar appears the margin is removed so the header stays on top of the nav bar without any extra margins.

a video to see it working: https://streamable.com/sc20h

heres the code:

```
var initial = 0;
var animateHeader = false;



//check if using mobile safari [returns true is mobile safari] =====

var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var iOS = !!ua.match(/iPad/i) || !!ua.match(/iPhone/i);
var webkit = !!ua.match(/WebKit/i);
var iOSSafari = iOS && webkit && !ua.match(/CriOS/i);
//===================================================

//This fades the header in and out on scroll, this can be ignored if working on a button===

function headerAnimate() {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var delta = 200;
    $(window).off("scroll").on("scroll", function (event) {
    if (!$(".box").hasClass("showing")) {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
         if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
             return;
         if (st > lastScrollTop) {
             $("header, #profilepopup, .search2 div").fadeOut("fast", "linear", function () {
               $("#glassM").css("font-size", "25px")
               $("#glassM").attr("class", "fa fa-search")
             })

            } else {
                $("header").fadeIn("fast", "linear")
            }
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
            $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function () {
                $("header").fadeIn("fast", "linear")
                  if(iOSSafari && animateHeader){
                     $("header").css("margin-bottom", "2%").animate({ marginBottom: "60px" })

            }

            }, 2500))
            if (st <= 600 && $("#search").is(":visible")) {
                $("#glassM").css("font-size", "30px")
                $("#glassM").attr("class", "fa fa-times")
            }
            lastScrollTop = st;
        }
    });
}
//==================================================================

//this is where the magic happens=====================

if (iOSSafari) {
    initial = $(window).height()
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).height() >= initial && animateHeader === false) {
            $("header").animate({ marginBottom: "60px" })
            animateHeader = true
        } else {
            $("header").animate({ marginBottom: "2%" }, function () {
                animateHeader = false
            })
        }
    })
}
//======================================================================
```